# Micrometer integration with Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, micrometer

I am migrating a Spring Cloud Stream application to the functional approach. Until now, I used the micrometer metrics that provided Spring Integration. See [Spring Integration - Micrometer Integration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/metrics.html#micrometer-integration).

Since the migration, the messages produced with StreamBridge don't generate metrics anymore. It seems to be because Spring Integration creates its metrics when the channel is defined as a bean and StreamBridge creates the channel on the fly instead.

Having said that, my questions are:

- Does SCS provide any other kind of metrics?
- If not, there is any way to force the application to declare the channels as beans beforehand?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

The following test shows that even defining the binding destination in properties the bean is not created at startup.

The versions used for the test are:

spring-boot: 2.5.4

spring-cloud-stream: 3.1.3

```java
class MessageChannelBeanTests {

    @Test
    void declaredOutputBindingsCreatesMessageChannelBeans() {

        TestChannelBinderConfiguration.applicationContextRunner(MessageChannelBeanTestsConfiguration.class)
                .withPropertyValues("spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myBinding.destination=myDestination",
                        "spring.cloud.stream.bindings.syso-in-0.destination=my-topic")
                .run(context -> {
                    final Map<String, MessageChannel> channels = context.getBeansOfType(MessageChannel.class);


                    /*
                     * Just to see which channels are declared as a bean
                     * The ouput is:
                     *
                     * nullChannel
                     * errorChannel
                     * syso-in-0
                     * my-topic.anonymous.errors
                     */
                    channels.entrySet()
                            .stream()
                            .map(Entry::getKey)
                            .forEach(System.out::println);

                    // Asserts that the channel is created as a bean even if the binding is set by properties
                    assertThat(channels)
                            .containsKey("myBinding");


                });

    }


    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    static class MessageChannelBeanTestsConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public Consumer<String> syso() {
            return System.out::println;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the MessageChannel beans created are:

nullChannel
errorChannel
syso-in-0
my-topic.anonymous.errors

But there is no trace for the 'myBinding'

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue, please check what spring cloud version you are using as from version 4 this integration was deprecated - please see this link https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2758
Sorry I just noticed that you are using version 3 so it should not apply to you. I will still leave my answer as it may be useful to some.
I hope this has helped.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you define a property for a non-existing binding it will be created ahead of time as a bean. For example, let's say in messaging system you have a destination called `myDestination` (queue, topic etc). Than you can have something like this

`spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myBinding.destination=myDestination`

and the use bridge and send it to `myBinding`.

Comment: It seems it is not working for me. I do not know if I am doing something wrong... I have just updated the question to show a test to check it (the same is happening in my application). Thanks Oleg to take a look of it.